# Solidify on Angle

Tags: modifiers, edges

How do I solidify an object with angled edges? The solidified edges run along the z axis not the natural edges of the object. Is there way to make it look natural?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. Just two changes in the Solidify modifier.

1. Set *Mode > Complex*
2. *Boundary > Flat*
3. Done.

[image: List item]